# Is there a pytorch method to check the number of cpus?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I can use this `torch.cuda.device_count()` to check the number of GPUs. I was wondering if there was something equivalent to check the number of CPUs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just use this :

```
os.cpu_count()
```

Answer (score 5):

At present pytorch doesn't support multiple cpu cluster in DistributedDataParallel implementation. So, I am assuming you mean number of cpu cores.

There's no direct equivalent for the gpu count method but you can get the number of threads which are available for computation in pytorch by using

> torch.get_num_threads()

Comment: A little late to the party, but it is worth noting that `get_num_threads` doesn't really get the number of threads that are available to the user, but the number of threads SET by the user. It is initialized to the correct number, but if you run `torch.set_num_threads(1024); print(torch.get_num_threads())`, it will show `1024`, no matter how many threads your processor can support... A better way would be `os.cpu_count()`

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles across it these days, the `gloo` backend of `DistributedDataParallel` is now available for distributed training across multiple cpus.